# looping through mySQL and print as json

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to loop through a MYSQL database using two GET requests. However it does not seem to work? This is the message i get back:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in /path on line 13
[]
```

here is my code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','db');

$limit = $_GET['limit'];
$lastid = $_GET['lastid'];



$all_news = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY news.date DESC LIMIT ?, ?"); 
$all_news->bind_param("ii", $lastid, $limit);
$all_news->execute();
$all_news->bind_result($id, $url, $image_url, $date, $news_text, $referer_img);

$rows = array();
while($all_news->fetch()) {
    $rows[] = array($id, $url, $image_url, $date, $news_text, $referer_img);
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got `select *`, but are binding only ONE variable to the result columns. If you only want the one column, then explicitly select only that one column:

```
SELECT field_you_want FROM news ...
```

Comment: i just want to add all the rows into the rows variable? do i really need to declare all MYSQL fields to do that?

Comment: Yes, you do. bind_result binds individual result fields to individual variables. with this method, you can't just do `mysqli_fetch_row()` and get an array of the result: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Comment: i've added the variables in question? how can i now add it to rows array in while query?

Answer (score 0):

that error is because you are only binding one param, and your statement contains two variables.

Comment: read again. the error is from `bind_result`. the input placeholders are just fine.